# PowerShell | Argument completer not working when a file with the required criteria is not in the current working directory

Tags: powershell, arguments, get-childitem, powershell-core, powershell-7.3

I've tried 2 argument completers so far for [my module](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/blob/main/WDACConfig/Deploy-SignedWDACConfig.psm1) to only show me the files with `.cer` extension when I press TAB button.

Here is one of them

```
$ArgumentCompleterCertPath = {
    Get-ChildItem | where-object { $_.extension -like '*.cer' } | foreach-object { return "`"$_`"" }   
}
Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName "Edit-SignedWDACConfig" -ParameterName "CertPath" -ScriptBlock $ArgumentCompleterCertPath
```

And here is the other one

```
[ArgumentCompleter({
            param($commandName, $parameterName, $wordToComplete, $commandAst)
      
            # Get the current path from the command
            $path = $commandAst.CommandElements |
              Where-Object { $_.ParameterName -eq 'Path' } |
              Select-Object -ExpandProperty Argument
      
            # Resolve the path to a full path
            $resolvedPath = Resolve-Path -LiteralPath $path
      
            # Get the files with .cer extension in the resolved path
            $files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $resolvedPath -Filter *.cer
      
            # Create an array of completion results from the file names
            $completions = foreach ($file in $files) {
              [System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult]::new($file.Name, $file.Name, 'ParameterValue', $file.Name)
            }
      
            # Return the completions
            return $completions
          })]
```

They both work when there is a certificate file in the current directory, but if there isn't any, they suggest any files with any extensions, even folders, when I press TAB.

What I want from them is:

1. Do not show wrong files if there isn't any files that meets the argument completer's criteria
2. if the current working directory doesn't contain any files that meets the argument completer's criteria, recursively search sub-directories to find a good file and even if recursive search didn't find any file, do not show wrong files when TAB is pressed.

For my specific situation, I put the certificate file inside the 2nd sub-directory of the current working directory.

I tried adding

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'
```

to them but that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- By default, **PowerShell *falls back* to its *default* tab-completion whenever a *custom* completer returns nothing** (which is technically the `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value` singleton), which makes it perform the usual completion of all file and subdirectory names in the current directory.

  - **You can *suppress* this fallback behavior if you return `$null` instead**, so that if your custom completer found no matches, no completions are offered at all.

    - **Caveat**: As of of PowerShell 7.3.4, this seemingly **only works with [`Register-ArgumentCompleter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/register-argumentcompleter) calls**, not with parameter-individual [`ArgumentCompleter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ArgumentCompleterAttribute) attributes using *script blocks*, and **it isn't clear if this an officially supported mechanism or if there even is one**.

      - See [GitHub issue #19628](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19628).
    - However, as [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) has discovered, **fallback *can* also be prevented** if you **use the `ArgumentCompleter` attribute *with a custom class that implements [`IArgumentCompleter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.IArgumentCompleter)*** rather than with a *script block*.

      - In fact, the logic is *reversed* then: use `return $null` as an *opt-in* to falling back to default completion.
      - See Santiago's [sample code](https://gist.github.com/santisq/ad07e2e3913de981c4d2e06f41e6ddb4#file-thing-doesnt-work-with-scriptblock-ps1).
  - As an aside, as of PowerShell 7.3.4:

    - PowerShell's default tab-completion is overzealous in that it performs file/directory-name completion even for parameter types where that doesn't make any sense (e.g. `[int]`) - see [GitHub issue #14147](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14147)
- As Santiago points out, implementing *unconstrained* use of `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` in a tab-completer is problematic, as it could result in a potentially prohibitively lengthy operation; however, you can use the `-Depth` parameter to limit the recursion to a fixed depth.

  - E.g., `-Depth 1` limits the lookups to the content of the input directory itself and that of its *immediate* subdirectories.

Therefore, try something like the following:

```
$ArgumentCompleterCertPath = {
  # Note the use of -Depth 1
  # Enclosing the $results = ... assignment in (...) also passes the value through.
  ($results = Get-ChildItem -Depth 1 -Filter *.cer | foreach-object {  "`"$_`"" })
  if (-not $results) { # No results?
    $null # Dummy response that prevents fallback to the default file-name completion.
  } 
}
Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName "Foo" -ParameterName "CertPath" -ScriptBlock $ArgumentCompleterCertPath
```

Comment: Thank you, using `$null` did it ^^ What do you think of the idea where I don't set a static depth value but make it so that it first checks depth 0 for any valid files, if it finds any then stops, but if it doesnt, starts checking depth 1 and so on.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @SpyNet; please also see the update re using `IArgumentCompleter`, based on Santiago's feedback. Re no fixed `-Depth` value. That should work, though, depending on the number of levels, could get slow.

Comment: @SpyNet, another option is to use a fixed `-Depth`, after all, and group the results by the number of path components, then use the group with the lowest number, along the lines of: `(Get-ChildItem *.cer -Depth 2 | Group-Object { ($_.FullName -replace '[^/\\]').Length })[0].Group`